# Problema em converter String para Date

Tags: java, data

Estou com um projeto para fazer e não estou conseguindo converter `String` para `Date`. Quero comparar a data atual com a data da consulta que está no textField *Data*, e se a data atual ja passou da data marcada,quer dizer que a consulta ja foi realizada e assim deletar ela do Banco de dados. Porém não estou conseguindo comparar datas. Aqui vai o código comentado as duvidas

```
 public void PegaData(String dataa) throws ParseException
{
 Date data = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
 SimpleDateFormat formatardata = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

 Date dataA =(Date)formatardata.parse(dataa);  //Tentei fazer casting mas nao rolou

 if(dataA.after(data)){
     btConsulta.setEnabled(true);
     System.out.println("data passada");
 }
 else{
       btConsulta.setEnabled(false);
       System.out.println("data no prazo");
      }
 }
```

retornou a  excessão

> (nov 29, 2016 2:56:11 PM projetojava1.Agenda listaValueChanged
>   GRAVE: null
>   java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "  -  -    ")

Código Completo

```
public class Agenda extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ManipulaBanco dado;
    DefaultListModel l;
    String nomeMedico;

    public Agenda() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        dado = new ManipulaBanco();
        Ativacao(false);


    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtPaciente = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btAgendar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtID = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        lista = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        txtData = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        txtNascimento = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        txtHoras = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtConfirma = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btConsulta = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Paciente:");

        jLabel2.setText("Data:");

        jLabel3.setText("Horário");

        btAgendar.setText("Agendar");
        btAgendar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btAgendarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Voltar");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel6.setText("Data de Nascimento");

        jLabel4.setText("N°  de Identificação:");

        txtID.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtIDActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Ok");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lista.addListSelectionListener(new  
          javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent 
             evt) {
                listaValueChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(lista);

        try {
            txtData.setFormatterFactory(new 
      javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new 
      javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("##/##/####")));
        } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            txtNascimento.setFormatterFactory(new 
       javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new 
       javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("##/##/####")));
        } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            txtHoras.setFormatterFactory(new 
         javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new 
         javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("##:##")));
        } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        jLabel5.setText("Confirmação");

        txtConfirma.setEditable(false);

        btConsulta.setText("Consulta ja realizada");
        btConsulta.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btConsultaActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new   
      javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(

       layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, 
         layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)

      .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(txtPaciente, 
              javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 216, 
               javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)

       .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 
       12, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, 
        javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, 
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)

                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                .addComponent(btAgendar)

     .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addGap(79, 79, 79))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()

  .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup
     (javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(txtID, 
      javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 164, 
         javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)

      .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.
     ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton4, 
      javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, 
         javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))

      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup
        (javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(btConsulta)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup
         (javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup
             (javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                                .addComponent(jLabel5,  
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup
           (javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup
             (javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(txtNascimento, 
          javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80,

       javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(txtData, 

javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(txtHoras, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 79, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addComponent(txtConfirma, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 139, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addComponent(txtID, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton4))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(txtPaciente, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                .addComponent(txtNascimento, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addComponent(txtData, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addComponent(txtHoras, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(txtConfirma, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel5)))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))

     .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 18,  
     Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btConsulta)

     .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)

     .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE 
     )
                    .addComponent(btAgendar)
                    .addComponent(jButton3))
                .addGap(20, 20, 20))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Principal principal = new Principal();
        principal.setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        nomeMedico = dado.Medicos(txtID.getText());


        if (txtID.getText().equals("") || txtData.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Por favor Insira o seu número  
        de identificação de médico e a Data");

        } else if (nomeMedico == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "ID Invalido");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Seja Bem vindo Dr."+nomeMedico);
            carregaLista();
            Ativacao(true);
        }

    }                                        

    private void listaValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                   

        String[] resultado = dado.consultaPaciente(lista.getSelectedValue());
        txtPaciente.setText(resultado[0]);
        txtNascimento.setText(resultado[1]);
        txtHoras.setText(resultado[2]);
        txtConfirma.setText(resultado[3]);

        boolean confirmacao;

        confirmacao=txtConfirma.getText().equals("Confirmado");

        if(confirmacao)
        {
            btAgendar.setEnabled(false);
            txtData.setEnabled(false);
            try {
                PegaData(txtData.getText().replace("/", "-"));
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Agenda.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,      

            ex);
            }
        }
        else{
           btAgendar.setEnabled(true);
           txtData.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }                                  

    private void txtIDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    private void btAgendarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        dado.agendaDia(txtData.getText(), txtPaciente.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data agendada para o paciente: " + 

        txtPaciente.getText());
        limpaCampo();
    }                                         

    private void btConsultaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if(txtPaciente.getText().equals("")){
    btConsulta.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else{
    btConsulta.setEnabled(true);
    dado.deletaPaciente(txtPaciente.getText());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Consulta finalizada com sucesso");
    limpaCampo();
    }

    }                                          

    public void limpaCampo() {
        txtPaciente.setText("");
        txtNascimento.setText("");
        txtData.setText("");
        txtHoras.setText("");
    }

    public void carregaLista() {
        nomeMedico = dado.Medicos(txtID.getText());
        l = new DefaultListModel();
        ArrayList<String> usuarios = dado.listarPacientes(nomeMedico);
        for (int i = 0; i < usuarios.size(); i++) {
            l.addElement(usuarios.get(i));
        }
        if(l.isEmpty()){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Nenhum paciente no   
       momento");}
        else
        lista.setModel(l);
    }

    public void Ativacao(boolean resposta) {
        txtPaciente.setEnabled(false);
        txtData.setEnabled(resposta);
        txtNascimento.setEnabled(false);
        txtHoras.setEnabled(false);
    }

    public void PegaData(String dataa) throws ParseException
    {
     Date data = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
     SimpleDateFormat formatardata = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

     Date dataA =(Date)formatardata.parse(dataa);  

     if(dataA.after(data)){
         btConsulta.setEnabled(true);
         System.out.println("data passada");
     }
     else{
           btConsulta.setEnabled(false);
           System.out.println("data no prazo");
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Altere o trecho onde você chama o método `PegarData` para `PegaData(txtData.getText());` ou a máscara de data dentro deste método para `dd-MM-yyyy`.

A mascara de formatação atual da sua data é `dd/MM/yyyy`, e você está substituindo a barra por traço, o que estoura a exceção, já que a data não chega com a formatação da máscara informada.

Se não der certo, provavelmente o problema pode está no valor que está chegando para ser "parseado", a julgar pelo erro, parece que está chegando apenas a máscara que você aplicou no campo `txtData`(por isso que exibe `Unparseable date: " - - "`), sem nada preenchido.

Comment: Fiz isso, mas retornou o mesmo erro, a unica diferença é que ao invés de "-" retornou "/"

Answer (score 1):

Parece que o parâmetro `dataa` do método  `PegaData(String dataa)` 
não esta vindo com o valor que você espera.
Me parece que é um problema antes de chamar a função, ou seja, a forma como vc está pegando a data do edit.

Comment: Verdade reparei um erro aqui, vou dar uma olhada e volto com o retorno

Comment: Bom, arrumei a parte e agora está vindo com o valor esperado, retornou isso a data " 26/11/2016" exatamente como está, porém deu outro erro que segue embaixo:                                                         Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Comment: Parece q agora é uma mistura de tipos.. vc ta usando Date do java.util e  Date do java.sql

Comment: remove os imports do java.sql.Date e tenta usar so o java.util.Date

Comment: Obrigado amigo, era isso Valeu

Comment: Disponha ...tamo ai pra isso .. =)